# How to add GtkMozEmbed browser into a tab with Ruby/Glade/GtK?

Tags: ruby, gtk, pygtk, mozilla, glade

I am trying to add a browser using GtkMozEmbed into a gui I am designing using Glade. I want the browser to take up a tab in a notebook widget, but I cannot figure out how to actually do this. I am wondering what container to use to put the browser in, and the associated ruby code to actually embed the browser in this container. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing eventually was to insert a window element into the tab, and in the ruby code associated with the glade file configure the GTKMozEmbed there. I do not think it is possible to get it setup using the Glade GUI, so you will have to get down into the code for this.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new tab with any widget use [this](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk::Notebook#append_page).